# Bridge PPPoS with ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, bridge, ppp

I have a PC on a test bench with 2 interfaces, enp2s0 and enp3s0. The IPs are public and obtained with DHCP, based on the interfaces MACs. There is a second computer on my bench, a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 3, which I want to expose on the internet. The RPi and bench sever are connect together through PPP, over a serial connection. On both side the ppp interface is called ppp0.

How can I bridge ppp0 and enp3s0, so that the RPi CM3+ accessible from the public IP? I'm lost among linux's many bridge and tunnel options...

[image: block diagram of current configuration]

My organization doesn't allow me to do routing or use switches. Any solution that minimize the chance of me wrecking the rest of the network would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The IPs are public and obtained with DHCP, based on the interfaces MACs.

Which means that when bridged the ppp interface would need to get a third public IP obtained with DHCP. Which won't work with ppp.

> bridge ppp0

Even if ppp0 wouldn't need a public IP, it's a **point-to-point** connection, as the name implies. So you cannot bridge it.

> so that the RPi CM3+ accessible from the public IP?

The simplest way is to enable forwarding on the Bench PIC, NAT ppp0 on either of the external NICs, and add port forwarding rules. (Google, there's hundreds of tutorials). This would mean **some** ports on the RPi will be accessible under the given external IP, potentially under different port numbers. And the Rpi can access **all** of the internet. Which will work if there's a known number of services running on the Rpi which need to be accessed.

If the Rpi **has** to have a third public IP, add a VPN that's bridgeable on top of the ppp0 connection (which will cause additional overhead), then bridge the resulting tun/tap interface.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve what I wanted without a third public IP or VPN.

I used DNAT and SNAT with broad rules. Many sources suggest MASQUERADE, but if multiple internet facing interfaces are available, the one with the lower metric will get both the local and PPP traffic and break routing. MASQUERADE doesn't allow to specify a specific source IP, but SNAT does.

I added the following iptables rules:

```
-A FORWARD -i enp3s0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o enp3s0 -j ACCEPT
-t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.5.2
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.5.2 -j SNAT --to-source <enp3s0's ip>
```

IP forwarding was enabled:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Idealy, a script could configure the SNAT rule source ip after DHCP configuration. In my case the ip is attributed indefinitely so a static rule is ok.

Edit: After dirkt's suggestion and catching some outgoing packets on the wrong interface, I added a new network namespace. The full script that bring up the interfaces is now:

```
ip netns add bridged
ip link set enp3s0 netns bridged
ip netns exec bridged ip link set dev enp3s0 up
ip netns exec bridged dhclient enp3s0

ip netns exec bridged iptables -A FORWARD -i enp3s0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec bridged iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o enp3s0 -j ACCEPT
ip netns exec bridged iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.5.2
ip netns exec bridged iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.5.2 -j SNAT --to-source [my internet ip]
ip netns exec bridged echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 raw
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 1000000
ip netns exec bridged pppd /dev/ttyUSB1 1000000 10.0.5.1:10.0.5.2 local noauth debug nodetach dump nocrtscts passive persist maxfail 0 holdoff 1
```

I'm not sure why DHCP doesn't run by default in the new namespace, but just calling dhclient once is working for now.

The firewall is down only in the namespace:

```
sudo ip netns exec bridged ufw disable
```

Comment: `MASQUERADE` by definition uses the IP on the interface it works on as the source IP. As you already specify the interface in the rules, it'll work fine, and it'll also work if for some reason enp3so's IP changes. If you want to use enp3s0 exclusively for the RPi, and enp2s0 for the Bench PC, I'd also suggest moving both enp3s0 and ppp0 to a new network namespace. That will solve the headache with having two IPs in the Bench PC. Finally, you don't need both DNAT and SNAT; the reverse NAT is handled by the connection tracker (conntrack).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details. I didn't have any luck with MASQUERADE but it's possible I missed a part of the rule.  I used iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE, maybe I should have added a source with -s 10.0.5.2? Or the namespace will be sufficient? For DNAT+SNAT, I need to initiate connections from both the Pi and remote clients, so I'm not sure reverse NAT is sufficient.